# How to create a new dataframe from existing dataframes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I have the following 2 dataframes:

df1

```
product_ID         tags
100         chocolate, sprinkles
101         chocolate, filled
102         glazed
```

df2

```
customer   product_ID
A            100
A            101
B            101
C            100
C            102
B            101
A            100
C            102
```

I should be able to create a new dataframe like this.

```
| customer | chocolate | sprinkles | filled | glazed |
|----------|-----------|-----------|--------|--------|
| A        | ?         | ?         | ?      | ?      |
| B        | ?         | ?         | ?      | ?      |
| C        | ?         | ?         | ?      | ?      |
```

Where the contents of cells represent the count of occurrences of product attribute.

I've used `merge` and got the following result

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1)
df3.drop(['product'], axis = 1)

customer       tags
A        chocolate, sprinkles
C        chocolate, sprinkles
A        chocolate, sprinkles
A        chocolate, filled
B        chocolate, filled
B        chocolate, filled
C        glazed
C        glazed
```

How do we get to the final result from here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in 2 steps:

1. Expand / flatten your dataframe with a series of comma separated strings.
2. Use [`pandas.crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) to tabulate your counts.

Here's an example assuming you have performed your merge and the result is `df`:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain

# split by comma to form series of lists
tag_split = df['tags'].str.split(',')

# create expanded dataframe
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'customer': np.repeat(df['customer'], tag_split.map(len)),
                        'tags': list(chain.from_iterable(tag_split))})

# use pd.crosstab for result
res = pd.crosstab(df_full['customer'], df_full['tags'])

print(res)

tags       filled   sprinkles  chocolate  glazed
customer                                        
A               1           2          3       0
B               2           0          2       0
C               0           1          1       2
```

Comment: worked like a charm! Could you explain the code you've done under the section #create expanded dataframes?

Comment: Sure, `np.repeat(df['customer'], tag_split.map(len))` repeats each value in the `customer` column by the respective length of tags. `list(chain.from_iterable(tag_split))` creates a single list of all the comma-separated elements in `tags`. You can read up the docs for [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) and [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

Answer (score 3):

Using `get_dummies`

```
df.set_index('customer').tags.str.get_dummies(sep=',').sum(level=0)
Out[593]: 
          chocolate  filled  glazed  sprinkles
customer                                      
A                 3       1       0          2
C                 1       0       2          1
B                 2       2       0          0
```